# Cannot add .net 4.5 assembly as reference to vb6

Tags: .net, vb6

I have a .NET assembly which uses .NET 4.5. I am attempting to add the assembly as reference to a VB6.0 application.

But I get the error:

> Can't add reference or file.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your assembly needs to expose COM interop, and needs to be registered using the regasm.exe tool (not regsvr32.exe).  Have you taken these two steps?

Comment: That's not possible, a .NET assembly does not contain an embedded type library.  You must use the type library that you generated from the assembly with Tlbexp.exe or Regasm.exe /tlb

Comment: @HansPassant when I have my C# classes setup for COM interop the Visual Studio build takes care of registering the TLB automatically. I've never needed to use the command line tools when I build on the same PC as the VB6 app though I know that is an option.